# If given a list of tuples representing ranges, how can you merge continuous ranges?

Tags: haskell

If given a list of tuples representing ranges like this:

```
[(0,10),(10,100),(1000,5000)]
```

I'd like to merge the tuples that represent contiguous ranges, so the result is this:

```
[(0,100),(1000,5000)]
```

Any elegant solutions?

Here's mine

```
mergeRanges :: [(Int, Int)] -> [(Int, Int)]
mergeRanges xs = foldr f [] (sort xs)
  where f new@(x,y) acc@((a,b):ys) =
            if y == a
            then (x,b):ys
            else new:acc
        f x acc = x:acc
```

*EDIT*: Ranges are non-overlapping

Comment: I would have thought mergeRanges [(0, 10), (10, 100), (10, 1000), (1000, 5000)] should give [(0, 5000)], but with your solution it gives [(0, 100), (10, 5000)] since each range is be merged with only one other range.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless this is a pattern that shows up more often in your program, I would just go for a direct recursion (untested code follows!):

```
mergeRanges (lo1,hi1) : (lo2,hi2) : rest)
    | hi1 == lo2 = mergeRanges ((lo1,hi2) : rest) 
             -- or (lo1,hi2) : mergeRanges rest, to merge only adjacent ranges
mergeRanges (interval:rest) = interval : mergeRanges rest
mergeRanges [] = []
```

(where you could optimize a bit by using `@`-patterns at the cost of clutter).

But if you really want to, you could use the following helper function

```
 merge :: (a -> a -> Maybe a) -> [a] -> [a]
 merge f [] = []
 merge f [x] = [x]
 merge f (x:y:xs) = case f x y of
     Nothing -> x : merge f (y:xs)
     Just z -> merge (z:xs) -- or z : merge xs
```

and give as first argument

```
 merge2Ranges (lo1, hi1) (lo2, hi2) 
     | hi1 == lo2 = Just (lo1, hi2)
     | otherwise = Nothing
```

I doubt that `merge` is in a library somewhere, since it's pretty specific to the problem at hand.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think the best solutions in this space probably will involve specialized data structures that maintain the invariant in question.  In Java-land, the Guava library has [`RangeSet`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/RangeSet.html), which does precisely this.

This is not a solution to your problem directly, but once I was playing around with this simple (too simple) implementation of "historical values" as a kind of binary search tree:

```
-- | A value that changes over time at discrete moments.  @t@ is the timeline type,
-- @a@ is the value type.
data RangeMap t a = Leaf a 
                 -- Invariant: all @t@ values in the left branch must be less than
                 -- the one in the parent.
                 | Split t (RangeMap a) (RangeMap a)

valueAt :: RangeMap t a -> t -> a
valueAt _ (Leaf a) = a
valueAt t (Split t' before since) 
    | t < t' = get t before
    | otherwise = get t since
```

The idea here is that `Split t beforeT sinceT` divides the timeline into two branches, one for values that held before `t` and a second for those that held since `t`.

So represented in terms of this type, your range set could be represented something like this:

```
example :: RangeMap Int Bool
example = Split 1000 (Split 100 (Split 0 (Leaf False) (Leaf False))
                                (Leaf False)) 
                     (Split 5000 (Leaf True) (Leaf False))
```

There are a few neat things about this, compared to the `[(since, until, value)]` representation that I've used in the past for similar applications:

1. The tree representation makes it impossible to have conflicting `a` values for the same time range.  `RangeMap` is a true function from `t` to `a`.
2. The tree representation guarantees that some `a` is assigned to every `t`.  Again, a `RangeMap` is a true function from `t` to `a`.
3. Since it's a tree and not a list, it supports log-time operations.

I did not go as far as working out a balanced tree representation for this or figuring out how to merge adjacent ranges with the same value, however...